# Transparency on decal not rendering correctly. (Decal Machine)

Tags: rendering, add-on, transparency

Were using decal machine (the plugin) to add some details on the floor of our scene.
We have used decal machine before and it worked before.

The problem is the square of discoloration that forms around the decal, as far as I know we haven't changed the decals.
Brighter lighting lessens the visibility of the square, but it's still there.

[image: You can clearly see it around the crack]

Anyone have a clue what's causing this?

EDIT:  Some extra information:
Some other HDRi's have better results where it is less visible but the problem is still there.

It works in a fresh scene, and so far I can pretty much transfer most of the scene to a new file and the decals work. (still working on this, will update if there are any assets which cause the problem.)

I still really want to know what causes this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Blender Problem, but rather a problem with decal machine. Have you tried contacting the authors through blender market or [their page](https://machin3.io/DECALmachine/docs/faq/#get-support)? It is a paid addon after all, they'll probably provide some support.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

I will contact the author, but I'm not sure it's the plugin. It worked in this same scene before and it all works in a fresh scene.

Comment: This is vital information, please edit it into your post. Can you append all your objects to a fresh scene one by one and check, when it stops working? Or slowly compare you new scene to the erroneous one?